# Rails - query works in view and controller in development, but only in view in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, production

I'm new to rails, so my question may have a simple answer. I am using rails 3.2.3. I have the following code to perform a search on my database:

`@search_results = User.search("test search")`

Where `search` is defined in my model. This code works perfectly for me when `@search_results = Data.search("test search")` is in either the view or controller in my development environment. In production, it works in the view, but not in the controller. I don't know why. Looking at my production log, there is a big difference in the SQL for the view and the controller:

When query is from a view in production, this is what I see in the log:

```
SELECT 'users'.* FROM 'users' WHERE (concat(field1, ' ', field2, ' ', field3) LIKE '%test%' AND concat(field1, ' ', field2, ' ', field3) LIKE '%search%'
```

That is exactly what I want. However, when query is from controller, the SQL turns into this:

```
SELECT 'users'.* FROM 'users' WHERE (field1 LIKE '%test search%' OR field2 LIKE '%test search%' OR field3 LIKE '%test search%')
```

I don't understand what my controller in the production environment is doing to create this change.

EDIT-Here is the `search` method:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    search_length = search.split.length
     find(:all, :conditions => [(["concat(field1, ' ', field2, ' ', field3) LIKE ?"] *        search_length).join(' AND ')] + search.split.map { |name| "%#{name}%" }) 
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

I am using MySQL on both production and development.

Comment: Please show us the actual `search` method, and tell us what database systems you're using in development and production. I suspect they are different.

Comment: I added the code for the `search` method. Both database systems in production and environment at MySQL. Thanks! In production, the search does work correctly when the search is in a view file. Just not when it is in the controller.

Comment: Just a note for the future: Please use four-space indenting for multiple lines of code.

Comment: Can you put a logger statement into the search method above in production and confirm without doubt that the same method is being called by both view and controller?

Comment: @mccannf I changed the names of the methods to check, and the result was the same. I have just now temporarily solved the problem by: moving all the code directly in the view AND by replacing `sessions[:search]` with `params[:search]`. (I was using a session variable for the search to reuse elsewhere.) Using params or directly typing a string into the search make it work perfectly. I don't understand why my session variables are mis-behaving in production, and not development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the second query is based on a former version of your search method.

Rails doesn't create a query like that out of thin air, so I think you probably have old code lying around somewhere that is generating that query.  Make sure you have restarted your production Rails app to get the latest code changes, and make sure you're calling the correct method on the correct object.

Comment: I've changed names of methods and objects and re-deployed often, but results have been the same. As I commented above, I've been able to determine the problem partly lies with my session vars in production. I don't know how `session[:search].to_s` (and other variations) yields a different result to `params[:search]` when passed to the method. The session variable was set earlier by `session[:search] = params[:search]`. However, making the switch has gotten my application working in production.

Comment: I've also noticed a couple of other places where my session variables mis-behave in production, but run smoothly in development. I don't understand why...

Comment: You might try adding `<%= session.inspect %>` to your layout or specific views to track how it changes as you step through the flow.

Comment: I added `<%= session.inspect %>` and now I see that some session variables are being set properly in development, but not in production. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Turns out I had an old version of the file that was being ignored in development, but causing conflicts in production.

Comment: @kevin: Great -- glad you find the solution!